# prove or disprove $\frac{1}{a_{i}}+\frac{1}{a_{j}}=\frac{1}{t},t\in N^{+}$

Tags: number-theory

Let $a_{i}(1\le i\le n)$ be positive integers such that $a_{1}<a_{2}<\cdots<a_{n}$, and that
$$\dfrac{1}{a_{1}}+\dfrac{1}{a_{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}=1$$

Prove or disprove there exsit $a_{i},a_{j}(i\neq j)$ such that
$$\dfrac{1}{a_{i}}+\dfrac{1}{a_{j}}=\dfrac{1}{t},t\in N^{+}.$$

Now I can't find any counterxaple for this problem. Maybe this is true? Thank you.
such
$$1=\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{6}$$
I find
$$\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{6}=\dfrac{1}{2}$$
such  as
$$1=\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{18}+\dfrac{1}{20}+\dfrac{1}{30}+\dfrac{1}{36}$$
I find
$$\dfrac{1}{18}+\dfrac{1}{36}=\dfrac{1}{12}$$
and so on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ 1= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{14} + \frac{1}{28}. $$

You can manually check that no two of them sum up to $\frac{1}{n}$. The rows and columns are $ \frac{1}{a_i}$, and the cell entries are $ \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a_i} + \frac{1}{a_j} } $.

[image]

I believe you can show that if there are 3 or 4 terms in the summation, the property is true. So I looked at 5 terms, and this appeared pretty quickly. You want to remove 'weird' stuff where possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment to Calvin Lin's solution to confirm that there are no solutions with 3 or 4 terms.

If you try to find a solution with three terms, one term has to be $1/2$ since the sum can otherwise at most be $1/3+1/4+1/5<1$. Hence, if $1/2+1/p+1/q=1$, we must have $1/p+1/q=1/2$.

For four terms a similar logic may be applied. Since $1/3+1/4+1/5+1/6<1$, the first term must be $1/2$ for the sum to be able to reach 1. If the second term is $1/3$, the last two terms must sum to $1-(1/2+1/3)=1/6$; if the second term is $1/4$, the last two terms must sum to $1/4$; if the second term is $1/6$, the last two terms must sum to $1/3$. This leaves $1/5$ as the only remaining option for the second term, otherwise the four terms will again not be able to sum to 1.

So we are looking for $1/2+1/5+1/p+1/q=1$ where $5<p<q$. Since $1/p+1/q=3/10$, this leaves $p=6$ and $p=7$ as alternatives, which would require that $1/q=2/15$ or $11/70$, neither of which are solutions.

For five terms, I find the following solutions using similar reasoning to restrict the options: $[2,3,11,14,231]$, $[2,3,11,22,33]$, $[2,4,7,10,140]$, $[2,4,7,14,28]$, $[2,5,6,8,120]$, and $[2,5,6,9,45]$.